# Whois with NodeJS Docker Image

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to get Whois working in NodeJS on a Dockerfile. I'm using [Whois-UX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whois-ux) (which just spawns a whois process with the `whois` linux command. I'm using the "node:argon" docker image, but it doesn't have whois installed. There doesn't seem to be a way to `apt-get install whois` inside the image either.

I then tried to use "ubuntu:12.04", but I'm having trouble running the app with it. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
WORKDIR /srv
ADD . /srv
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs git git-core whois
RUN npm install
CMD ["node /srv/server.js"]
```

So, there are two possible solutions that I don't know how to solve. Figure out how to get whois on the node:argon image, or get the ubuntu docker image to work. I'd rather get whois on node:argon, because of optimizations for NodeJS, but as long as it works, it'll do.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you try ssh-ing into your Docker image and run `which whois`, what output do you have?

Comment: @christophetd It shows up with no whois locations

Comment: What if you use the full path of the command, i.e. run `/usr/bin/whois`?

Comment: And if you manually run `sudo apt-get install -y whois` in your docker instance, does it work?

Comment: No, it's like the nodejs:argon doesn't have whois in its apt sources

Comment: Try: https://gist.github.com/christophetd/cd3652d36a07f3eb32e17498be670dc3

Answer (score 0):

Whelp. I got it.

I forgot to `apt-get update` before I `apt-get install`ed whois, so it didn't show the repository as being up.

```
FROM node:argon
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install whois

RUN npm install bower -g

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN bower install --allow-root

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

^ This worked.